# New Line in PHP Submit Message Form Not Working

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

Can I **overwrite** other rules just by editing this code to show new lines? Currently everything is in one line after submission. The code is:

```
$oForm->addElement(
        new $sEditorClass(
            t('Message:'),
            'message',
            [
                'required' => 1,
                'validation' => new \PFBC\Validation\Str(4)
            ]
        )
    );
```

The code showing the post is:

```
<p>
            {% Framework\Parse\Emoticon::init(
                Framework\Security\Ban\Ban::filterWord($post->message)
            ) %}
</p>
```

Comment: If it's HTML, use `<br>` for line breaks, or put pre-formatted text inside `<pre>...</pre>`

Comment: You can use `nl2br()` to convert newlines to `<br>`.

Comment: What framework is this? Add the appropriate tag.

Comment: <pre> tag works, but the problem is horizontal scrollbar. How can I avoid it with CSS?

Comment: Use `white-space: pre-line` style. That will do line wrapping and also obey newlines.

Comment: Works like a charm. The only problem is now is word break. I don't like my words to break into no meaningful parts.

Comment: What do you mean? You mean long words are being split across lines?

Comment: if a word long enough to split across lines is OK, the problem is even short words split across lines. I hope you now what I mean.

Comment: Please edit your answer with <pre>, I really don't like <span> for some reasons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space: pre-line` CSS.

This setting means:

> Sequences of white space are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

You can find other variations in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#Values)

```html
<pre style="display: flex; white-space: pre-line; text-align: left;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. 
Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</pre>
```

Comment: <pre style="display: flex; white-space: pre-line; text-align: left;"> Please answer with this code not span. The only issue of my code is word break.

Comment: I've added a code snippet, it's not breaking up words.

Comment: I prefer to solve this with <pre> tag and not use any <span> or <div> tags. Is it possible? If not, could you please use <span> and <div> tags inside <pre> tag?

Comment: You can use any of them, it doesn't seem to make a difference. `<pre>` uses a monospace font.

Comment: I'm using <pre>, the issue is word break please look at my code: `<pre style="display: flex; white-space: pre-line; text-align: left;">`

Comment: Also tried this `<pre style="display: flex;
                     text-align: left;
                    
  "><code style="white-space: pre-line">`

Comment: Also tried using <div> and <span> inside <pre>. None doesn't prevent word break.

Comment: I've updated my answer like that, I'm still not seeing any word breaks.

Comment: I get a break between `tempor` and `incididunt`, between `ut` and `aliquip`, between `in` and `voluptate`, and between `officia` and `desrunt`.

Comment: Any reason why it doean't work on my side? I've tested your code and it works with the test tool here. but not on my php code

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the framework you're using for rendering, I have no idea what that is.

Comment: It's using the formatting utf-8. Could be the cause of the problem?

Comment: No, character encoding shouldn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: I would accept your answer BTW. Thanks for your time